# Download pdf file in response to post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, pdf

I want a server-side report to be generated from a javascript object and returned as a PDF. In one request.
I've tried a windows.location.href with the object in the query string, but the query string gets too long.
I've also tried a jQuery post with the object as attachment like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/SalesCalls/SalesCallReport/GetReport",
        data: JSON.stringify(unmappedItem),
        timeout: 10000,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (response, status, request) {
            var disp = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            if (disp && disp.search('attachment') != -1) {
                var type = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });
                var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.location = downloadUrl;
            }
        }
});
```

I stole the code in the success callback from another post on stackoverflow. It transfers the object to the server alright, but the output somehow doesn't work, I just get a blank pdf. I can see response contains the binary pdf, so I'm somehow missing a step.
The fact that this runs only on modern browsers is no problem.

Comment: Interesting question, but: what's on the server side? Do you have the PDF ready and waiting for you? Or are you creating the PDF from scratch? What are you creating the PDF with? Is that process working if you call `/SalesCalls/SalesCallReport/GetReport` the *normal* way.

Comment: It's just not possible to download files using AJAX. You'll have to create an actual form (visible or not) and submit it.